# Generate single download url for multiple files in Google Cloud Storage

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I have my files residing in Google Cloud Storage bucket and I am using the java API to upload files there. In my application, for single file downloads, I am generating signed URLs but I want to provide a functionality where users can select multiple files and download them as a zip. Is there a way to achieve this with the current API?

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible with the current API.  You could do it yourself with a fairly simple AppEngine app though.